# libqxt compilation - mingw32-make exception

Tags: windows, qt, compiler-errors, mingw32, libqxt

I have a following problem with compiling libqxt.

configure.bat generates files, but displays some warnings:

```
c:\Users\Lukasz\Downloads\libqxt-libqxt-7e0d3396b765>configure.bat
   Testing for qmake...
   Testing for mingw32-make...
       Using mingw32-make.
   Testing for optional external libraries.
   If tests fail, some features will not be available.
   Testing for Berkeley DB...
       Berkeley DB disabled.
   Testing for Zero Conf...
       Zero Conf disabled.
   Configuration successful.
   Generating makefiles...
Project MESSAGE: building docs
Project MESSAGE: building core module
Project MESSAGE: building widgets module
Project MESSAGE: building network module
Project MESSAGE: building sql module
Project MESSAGE: building web module
Reading C:/Users/Lukasz/Downloads/libqxt-libqxt-7e0d3396b765/tools/3rdparty/qdoc
3/qdoc3.pro
Reading C:/Users/Lukasz/Downloads/libqxt-libqxt-7e0d3396b765/src/core/core.pro
Reading C:/Users/Lukasz/Downloads/libqxt-libqxt-7e0d3396b765/src/widgets/widgets
.pro
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: widgets
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: widgets
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: widgets
Reading C:/Users/Lukasz/Downloads/libqxt-libqxt-7e0d3396b765/src/designer/design
er.pro
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: widgets
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: widgets
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: widgets
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: widgets
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: widgets
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: widgets
Reading C:/Users/Lukasz/Downloads/libqxt-libqxt-7e0d3396b765/src/network/network
.pro
Reading C:/Users/Lukasz/Downloads/libqxt-libqxt-7e0d3396b765/tools/jsonrpcclient
/jsonrpcclient.pro
Reading C:/Users/Lukasz/Downloads/libqxt-libqxt-7e0d3396b765/src/sql/sql.pro
Reading C:/Users/Lukasz/Downloads/libqxt-libqxt-7e0d3396b765/src/web/web.pro
   Makefiles generated. Run mingw32-make now.
```

mingw32-make interrupts almost immediately with an exception:

```
c:\Users\Lukasz\Downloads\libqxt-libqxt-7e0d3396b765>mingw32-make
mingw32-make: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc00000fd, addr = 0x421963)
```

The source were downloaded from an official website. Running configure and mingw32-make is the way of compiling that is described in README file. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simple and unexpected - mingw32-make has big problems with parenthesis ( "(" signs ) in PATH environment variable. The solution is to remove from the PATH all directories that contain "(".

One can change PATH locally in the command line (while not changing it for any other programs) using syntax:
`set PATH=...`, e.g. my sanitized PATH was:

```
set PATH=C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin;C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\lib;C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
```

As for getting the current PATH value, use syntax: `echo %PATH%`.